How to create a single SDK in Yocto for multiple projects with different dependencies?
I'm currently working in a Yocto environment with multiple projects, each based on different layers. However, I always work on the same meta layer across these projects, with different recipes used in each project.
Here is the typical structure:
layers
|-- meta-my-layer
|-- meta-external-a
|-- meta-external-b

My code is delivered by meta-my-layer, but it is used in several instances of different Yocto projects. Each project has different external dependencies and supports different recipes. As a result, I am forced to use multiple instances of Yocto projects to work on my code.
Typically, I only need to download source code for one or two repositories, make changes, run tests, and deliver it. For this, I use Yocto's standard SDK.
However, due to the different external dependencies of each recipe/repository, I need multiple instances of Yocto's standard SDK. I am looking for a mechanism to create a single SDK that includes all the necessary tools to compile my code, while allowing me to switch sysroots to work on multiple projects without installing multiple SDKs.
What is the best way to achieve this in Yocto?

What prevents you from simply building an SDK that has all the dependencies of the other projects included? Also, if you'd build inside Yocto, I assume you already share the downloads and sstate-cache accross projects to speed it up?
